# Stuck in limbo in updating to nativescript 7

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I feel like I've done all the steps I was supposed to do to update, but my running in ios is still not working.

I'm looking at all the instructions and it just appears that things I thought were getting migrated automatically, didn't migrate. Can anyone tell from my package.json where I'm going wrong?

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.nsplantapp",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.3"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.2"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^3.0.1",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.1.0",
    "nativescript-algolia": "^1.2.3",
    "nativescript-angular": "^10.0.0",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.6.3",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^2.0.24",
    "nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "^7.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^9.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.24",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tns-android": "6.5.3",
    "tns-ios": "6.5.4",
    "tslint": "~5.19.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package.json is still for NS 6+, the packages listed there are not the ones needed for NS7.
For instance in NS7 there is no tns namespace in packages anymore except for compatibility in CLI.

Have a look here, [How to upgrade Nativescript](https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-announcement/)

in order to modify your package.json.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was getting an error I didn't previously see.

Comment: You're welcome! I suppose you updated the package.json too.. Happy New Year!

Comment: Yes, it was updated, but then I just kept running into other strange package mismatch problems. It created a nativescript.config.ts, but then it disappeared when updating something else, so I decided to start a new {N7} app and port over all my code one at a time. It's running now.

Comment: You should have used the ns migrate CLI command after upgrading the core Nativescript package, it would have upgraded the whole project without you having to manually create the config.ts file. You can try it maybe it'll salvage you some work and will be able to reuse the former project.